# Will periods(.) still be allowed in bucket names post path-style deprecation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, virtualhost, bucket

What I understand is : 
"Support for the path-style model continues for buckets created on or before September 30, 2020. Buckets created after that date must be referenced using the virtual-hosted model."
(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/).

Also, there is a known problem with Virtual-hosted model when using bucket names containing periods(.) and working in SSL mode (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html). 
(the workaround given is to use HTTP which is obviously insecure or change the certificate verification logic)

Now, what if I want to have my NEW bucket's name to contain a period (a very specific requirement for my project's hosted URL)  and still be secure (use SSL) and also cannot tamper my certification verification logic in the client?

Is there any alternate way?
Will AWS S3 still allow bucket name to contain periods(.) post path-style deprecation?

Comment: *"a very specific requirement for my project's hosted URL"*  Can you clarify the nature of that requirement?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the answer is not at this time but they are working on it.

From the same reference you posted it appears they are working on it but have not implemented support for `Bucket Names with Dots`:

> It is important to note that bucket names with “.” characters are perfectly valid for website hosting and other use cases. However, there are some known issues with TLS and with SSL certificates. We are hard at work on a plan to support virtual-host requests to these buckets, and will share the details well ahead of September 30, 2020.

**References**

[S3 Path Deprecation Plan](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a website on s3, and are talking about the requirement that the bucket name must match the domain name (and thus require periods), it is trivially easy to simply put aws cloudfront 'in-front' of s3, and the requirement that the bucket name matches the domain name goes away AND you can also use cloudfront to setup https - its very easy to do, and quite affordable - especially for low-volume sites.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was w.r.t the S3 client side. This has to be done on the S3 server side and I am sure there are multiple more ways to get pas this problem at the server end.